# pull to refresh crashes ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, pull-to-refresh

I'm using pull to refresh in my app for collection view but app is crashing with error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

I'm using asynchronous queue to get the data from server.

Following is my code to get the data from server and update ui on success:

```
     refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
     [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(startRefresh:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)startRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshcontrol
{
    dispatch_queue_t fetchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("fetch Queue", NULL);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     //webservice call which on success post notification
    });
}


- (void)onSuccess:(NSNotification *)success { //notification after success of webservice
    [storyCollectionView setHidden:NO];
    NSLog(@"fun:%s", __func__);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//in the main queue i'm ending refresing
        if ([refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
        } 

    [CollectionView reloadData];// reloading collection view
    }
                   );

  }
```

Comment: Can you show your UICollectionViewDataSource methods?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should reload your collection view or tableview after calling **refreshcontrol.endrefreshing**.
Like:-

```
@objc func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
        // Code to refresh table view
        //Do all other API Calling stuff here
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.tableviewList?.reloadData()
    }
```

It will work perfectly!! :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the data in your data model is inconsistent with with the UITableView's date source methods returns.

Answer (score 0):

In your collection view datasource check if the array is empty , you are trying to access an empty array, use below code to check array is empty and return 0.

```
if (array == nil){
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when performing pull to refresh . its default behaviour to reload table at that time your array becomes blank so it will be crash. so for this alloc your array after getting web service response.

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("fetch Queue", NULL);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 //webservice call which on success post notification
});
```

there is no required to use this methodall time . it reduce app performance. because it waiting for Queue or main thread becomes free.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your taking the values from array without checking the size of array